# Como deletar todos os arquivos de uma pasta usando o Shell do VB

Tags: vb.net

Estou tentando assim e não consigo:

```
Shell("CMD.exe /c ""C:\Users\""%username%""\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\""User Data""\Default\Cache\DEL *.* /Q""  ")
```

No caso a pasta é a do cache do GoogleChrome

NO DOS eu uso assim:

```
CD C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*.* /q
pause
```

Comment: Não vejo o uso nem do del, tão pouco do rmdir/rd para remoção do conteúdo neste seu exemplo. O cd é para trocar de diretório e não para excluir arquivos.

Comment: @ararog consegue me ajudar com um exemplo ?

Comment: del C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\\*.*

Comment: @ararog tipo esse ai eu fiz pra executar um arquivo txt vou te mandar o código se eu colocar um arquivo 1.txt dentro do cache ele abre eu não sei usar o delete sacou ? Não sei como colocar ele na linha ,

O comando que eu uso pra abrir fica assim ,
Shell("CMD.exe /c ""C:\Users\""%username%""\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\""User Data""\Default\Cache\1.txt""  ")

Comment: @ararog vou testar aqui , perai.

Comment: @ararog deu ruim, ele não executou o comando, alguma coisa está errada na linha escrita.

Comment: @ararog vou tirar o print

Comment: @ararog eu escrevi o código assim

Comment: @ararog
 Shell("CMD.exe del C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*.*")

Link da imagem do erro : http://i.imgur.com/CBvOw7G.png

Comment: No lugar de %username% tente simplesmente colocar o nome do usuário.

Comment: @ararog nada mesma coisa, deu erro denovo o mesmo erro da imagem.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, esta é uma pergunta de CMD (linha de comando), pois a linguagem usada para chamar o CMD é irrelevante para a dúvida em questão.

Segundo, que não dá pra assumir que o Chrome vai estar no disco C:

Assim, o local correto é `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, que já tem todos os detalhes para a pasta do usuário corrente. Isso se o Chrome for instalado no lugar padrão. O ideal seria procurar pelo registro.

Simplificando, usando a lógica da pergunta, a linha teria que ficar desta forma:

```
Shell("CMD.exe /c DEL /q ""%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*.*"" ")
```

Agora, cá entre nós, se é para usar VB, compensaria um procedimento em VB mesmo para limpar o diretório, em vez de chamar o CMD...

Comment: obrigado ; tomara que dê certo é porque o comando de deletar tem que ser executando de dentro do vb só por isso .

Eu sei fazer chamando um comando externo mais não queria usar na aplicação .

Comment: Em breve você vai entender o porque desse comando .

Comment: como posso deletar um arquivo por exemplo dentro dessa pasta .

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\

O arquivo que queria deletar é o History

Comment: @Perroni mesma coisa, só que troca  `\Default\Cache\*.*"" "` por `\Default\History"" "`